# How to use maven version plugin in branch

Tags: maven, dependencies, version

I use maven version range for the dependencies in my parent `pom`.It works fine when I do a build on snapshot or a release.
But how should I need to proceed when I want to use the specific version of dependencies in a branch ?

For example: when I use version range such as (1.2.0,) it will always fetch the latest jar from the nexus repository. The latest would be like 1.2.5 as of when I do a release, since the dependencies are getting changed over and over.Now the latest version of my dependencies is 1.2.8-SNAPSHOT

In branch when I want 1.2.5 version for my dependencies, it is always looking for the latest one which is 1.2.5+

How to resolve this, while searching for similar questions I found that it could be resolved using `maven-version-plugin`. That requires a changes in the pom to add the plugin. But is there a solution without changing the pom and getting exact version for a dependency?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution without changing the pom at this point, if I understand the scenario correctly: In the release of a prior version of your product, the version of one (or more) of its dependencies was not fixated to the version available at the time.  Now, in support of that previous release, the build has a different result than at the time of release.

There is no suggestion except to change the branch's pom to use the 'back' version available at the time of the release.  Consider it a short term fix to a bug in the release process.

Comment: Well thanks for your suggestion i am doing the same way as you mentioned for almost one year. Is there a fix available yet?